# How can I stream live webcam video using Adobe flex without using Flash server or Red5?

Tags: php, html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, red5

My hosting service doesn't allow Flash server or Red5 to be used on the shared hosting account, only with a VPS account.  This is something, I do not want to pay for.  I have managed to create a MXML application and successfully compile it into a .SWF file that will grab the user's live cam.  Now the problem I'm having is displaying that webcam to other users.  So I'm assuming I need some sort of server to send that video to, so that I can connect to it, and then display the stream.  Now my question is, is there a work around in which I don't need another server, such as Red5 or Flash server? Why can I not handle the live webcam myself and display the live stream using ActionScript3.0?

Comment: You may be able to use the Flash Player's Peer to Peer technology: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/ .  I don't know much about how it works, though.  If two clients are on the same Wifi network, I think you use a LocalConnection.

Comment: I've decided to require users to create a Ustream account and then embed the HTML link to their video stream into the site.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **[Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/)** as Reboog711 mentioned. **Its a peer-2-peer protocol.**

Well to answer your questions..

> is there a work around in which I don't need another server, such as
>   Red5 or Flash server?

- Yes, **you don't need any servers involved here**. Just connect to the service and get a token id. Exchange that token id with your remote end user and do the vice-versa, such that both of you can able to see yourselves.

> Why can I not handle the live webcam myself and display the live
>   stream using ActionScript3.0?

- Who said you can't ;) ? You can very well control the settings including the webcam video size, aspect ratio, quality, bandwidth , etc everything using your actionscript 3.0.